# Search file in gitlab-ci.yml job

Tags: powershell, shell, gitlab-ci

I have a job in gitlab-ci.yml that look like this

```
job_name:
  script:
    - .../ExeName.exe > Output.txt      
  needs:
    - ...
  stage: ...
  tags:
     - ...
```

Edit: jobs are using powershell

`ExeName.exe` is an executable created by visual studio. `Output.txt` contains the output of the program and is created when `ExeName.exe` is run. I want to know if a string exists in the `Output.txt` file. If the string exists, the job should fail, if it exists the job should pass. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the job you consider runs an image that contains standard POSIX tools.

So in particular, you may want to rely on `grep`:

either writing:

```yaml
job_name:
  script:
    - .../ExeName.exe > Output.txt
    - '! grep -e "forbidden string" Output.txt'
```

(as by default, `grep` succeeds if it finds the string, while you are interested in the opposite behavior, hence the shell negation operator `!`) or:

```yaml
job_name:
  script:
    - .../ExeName.exe > Output.txt
    - grep -q -v -e "forbidden string" Output.txt
```

or you may want to manually use an `if` if you want to display more text in the logs:

```yaml
job_name:
  script:
    - .../ExeName.exe > Output.txt
    - if grep -q -e "forbidden string" Output.txt; then echo "Found forbidden string"; false; else echo "OK."; fi
```

As an aside, you might be interested in setting your generated text file `Output.txt` as a [job artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html).

Comment: My jobs are using powershell(my bad for not mentioning it). I tried something close to this: (Get-Content output.txt| select-string -pattern "forbidden string").length -ne 0 . It simply returns false and the jobs succeeds. Edit: I want Output.txt test in this job, so i do not need an artifact. Thank you for the suggestion.